# How to find out if an object is a SQLAlchemy mapped one?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I find out if an object is a SQLAlchemy mapped one?
It means if it is derived from `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()`.
Using `isinstance()` doesn't work in my tests.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table'
    _oid = sqlalchemy.Column('oid', sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)


model = Model()

# of course this is False
print ( Base == sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base() )

# this can not work even
print( isinstance( model,
                   sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base() ) )

# but 'Base' is unknown at this point
# I need a generalized way to find out if a given instance is mapped
# by SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insp = sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect(model)
```

This would raise an `sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable` when it is not a SQLAlchemy object.

See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect for details.

Comment: `type(type(model)) == type(sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base())` worked, too. But I am not sure if this is elegant.

Comment: Buthz: I think this comment you put here is actually a better answer then the answer you gave.  You should post this comment as its own answer.

Comment: My comment looks dirty and is hard to read. My answer raise a nice exception what would be the pythonic way. When you think my comment is better, then please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by your comment [on your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676936/1286571), [@buhtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4865723/buhtz), but uses `isinstance`, which has the benefit of working for subclasses of `DeclarativeMeta` (however unlikely that is).

```
isinstance(type(model), sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.DeclarativeMeta)
```

Comment: This won't work for entities that aren't mapped using declarative, for example [imperative mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#imperative-mapping).  It would also fail if `declarative_base` is passed a metaclass that doesn't inherit from `DeclarativeMeta`.